# Could not locate magento/magento2-base/composer.json file

Tags: magento2, composer

I'm getting constant errors as the below message but I'm not sure where to start by fixing this issue:

> [2016-12-15 02:35:01] setup-cron.ERROR: Could not locate
>   magento/magento2-base/composer.json file.

Comment: Run first `compose update` &  `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`, then try again on Magento Root Folder

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It happened the same for me when Magento 2 was cloned from the git repository. As the [documentation](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/install/post-install-config.html#post-install-cron) mentions, in such case you should run only one cron job, the

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/php /var/www/magento2/bin/magento cron:run | grep -v "Ran jobs by schedule" >> /var/www/magento2/var/log/magento.cron.log
```

because the other two are for those who installed Magento from the downloadable package.

Answer (score 0):

Known issue, it has been discussed on github.

Check here: https://github.com/magento/devdocs/issues/778